# Is there a way to only mock functions only when I need in Google mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I have a mock

```
class mockA: public A{
    public:
        .......
        MOCK_MOTHOD0(functionB, bool());
}
```

and functionB is a protected virtual function in class A. I can use the mock method in my test like

```
 TEST(test,testA){
    .....
    mockA objA;
    EXPECT_CALL(objA, functionB()).WillOnce(Return(true));
}
```

which works well. But i also have some test cases that I do not want to mock functionB. What should I do?  I can think of one way is that create another mock class with the exact same content as mockA but not having line  `MOCK_MOTHOD0(functionB, bool());`. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `class mockA` defined in the `.....` of the test body?

Comment: You might be interested might [`NiceMock` or `StrictMock`](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#NiceStrictNaggy).

Comment: @Eljay why do I need to define a class?     class mockA is in  `A.test.cc` file and `class A` is in another file `A.hh`

Comment: *why do I need to define a class?*  Did you have a reason to define `mockA`?

Comment: @Eljay.  because i would like to mock some functions in class A in my gtest including `functionB`. and in my case `functionB` is special because sometimes I need to mock it sometimes I do not need it to be mocked. And for other functions like `functionC/D/E`, i will still need them to be mocked. So i was wondering do I have to create another almost exact same class if I just do not need mock functionB in some cases. If so, I will have to reuse code to mock functionC/D/E

Comment: When I mock a class for a test, I mock the class for that test.  If I have 10 tests, each test which uses a mocked class in its own way, I have 10 mocked classes, each of which is particular for a specific test.  It is possible to have a single mocked class, but I've found that has far too high a coupling cost for each of the tests.  I follow the **WET** (*write expressive tests*) principle for unit tests, so that tests are standalone, without hidden dependencies, and complete.

Comment: I tend to mock interface, so all functions are mocked. I might have different factories if some mocked functions are similar between tests, but generally I can just directly mock the wanted function, or one factory is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#delegating-calls-to-a-parent-class solves exactly what you want. In all tests you just should use `EXPECT_CALL`, but for the special test - delegate to the concrete class.